# Output power if X players in radius Y around the command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm new to Command Blocks in Minecraft and want to solve this problem:

If X players in radius Y around the command block, then output power.

I read a bit about `testfor` and tried things like `testfor @p[r=5,c=2]` which I hoped would only output power if there are at least 2 players in a radius of 5. Doesn't work. Then I only tried `testfor @p[r=5]` and added a comparator block at the end and hoped it would output as much power players are in the given radius. Doesn't work.

How can I actually test how many players are in a specific radius? How do I only output power if a given number of players is passed?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are supplying a pulse of redstone power to the command block, right?  Command blocks don't just output willy-nilly.

Comment: Unless u r in a version above 1.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@p` targets the closest player so will only find 1 player each time, even if more are within the radius you have given.

`@a` targets all players with the arguments given, so should work for either of the methods you are trying.